# call php script every minute

Tags: php, cron

I want to call a php script every minute. My scriptruntime on my webserver is about 90 sec.
I thought doing it with cronjobs but i have to pay for that service. Is there an other possibility?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: might I ask why you need this script to run that often? Usually that is only required with a lot of traffic...at which point you would be running a vps at the least...

Comment: i have to check a mysql db for an timestamp if that timstamp was 20 minutes ago it has to call a function. The oint is the users can submit a timestamp when they want. so i have to check every minute wheather 20 min are over or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a script on Google AppEngine to "ping" yours ([Scheduled Tasks](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) to be more precise). It's free :-)

Comment: could you please describe that with more precision :)?

Comment: @rdesign: create a Scheduled Task on GAE (it's a cron job that calls a script in your GAE project) and have the "cron script" issue an "HTTP GET" (or whatever) to your server. This would trigger the PHP script on your server.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. You could have the script call itself 60 seconds after it completes. But if the script crashes, it won't restart.

Something like sleep(60*1000) to cause it to sleep for 60 and then just either call the page again, or start the script over at the top.

Comment: Well, cron is the accepted tool for this, anything else is a hack.

Comment: `sleep(60*1000)` would put PHP to sleep for almost 17 hours!

Comment: That's fine, Alex, the longer php sleeps the better this world gets.

Answer (score 0):

Try some [online cron services](http://www.onlinecronservices.com/). This is more or less the same jldupont suggested, though.

Depending on the php setup you might be able to launch your script with

```
php /wherever/yourscript.php </dev/null &>/dev/null
```

command line from inside php.